# Do Cron_schedule table collects log cleaning status too?

Tags: magento-1, log, log-cleaning

Hi If magento fails to run the log cleaning process as per the configuration then where it does saves the error_log (or) failure status? Magento doesn't clean the log tables periodically.

Note: I can't set Cron from cpanel(WHM) to do this automatically, as I don't have option.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: If you cannot set up a cron job to run Magento's cron trigger (either `cron.sh` or `cron.php`) regularly, then Magento's internal cron jobs don't run. If your hosting provider won't let you run cron jobs, then you will have to call cron.php periodically by calling it remotely with curl or wget.

Comment: I have run http://example.com/cron.php however this never cleared the log tables ?

Comment: After a long time ../cron.php executed with folowing error email exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Too late for the schedule.'

Comment: See answer below, `cron.php` trigger has to happen often enough to run job within its set execution time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot set up a cron job to run Magento's cron trigger (either cron.sh or cron.php) regularly, then Magento's internal cron jobs don't run.

If your hosting provider won't let you run cron jobs, then you will have to call cron.php periodically by calling it remotely with curl or wget.

Two things to finish out the setup:

1. you must run `cron.php` at least every 15 minutes minimum so you don't get "too late for the schedule" because the job got set but didn't run within the expiry time period. Magento cron jobs are a two step process, the job gets set on the first trigger (scheduled), then then on next trigger, it gets run (at about the scheduled time after the nearest trigger runtime)
2. you must go to **System->Config->Advanced->System** to complete the Log Cleaning setup.

[image]

Generate schedule information (System->Config->Advanced->System) under the Cron windowshade for a system that's running `cron.sh/cron.php` every 15 minutes.

**Note:** AOE_Scheduler is being run on this system and the extra fields are there for it. If you're running AOE_Scheduler and you're running a cron trigger (`cron.php`) every 15 minutes, you need to set the AOE_Scheduler Heartbeat Task Schedule appropriately to be every 15 minutes.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example on this alone please. "call cron.php periodically by calling it remotely with curl or wget."

Comment: I am running cron.php from my browser periodically and schedule generates, However status are pending,... think it should completes after scheduled time

Answer (score 2):

Normally Magento would push a cron error via email to the email address you have entered in the Admin for this. Optionally errors would be logged to `exception.log` in the `var/log` directory.

**[EDIT]**

You can monitor your cronjob activity with [Aoe_Scheduler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler). That might also give you some more insight into whats going on.

**[END EDIT]**

I usually turn of logging since it's not very useful and does a lot of queries per page view. You can turn them off via a modules `config.xml` by adding

```
<frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch>
                <observers><log><type>disabled</type></log></observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch>
            <controller_action_postdispatch>
                <observers><log><type>disabled</type></log></observers>
            </controller_action_postdispatch>
            <customer_login>
                <observers><log><type>disabled</type></log></observers>
            </customer_login>
            <customer_logout>
                <observers><log><type>disabled</type></log></observers>
            </customer_logout>
            <sales_quote_save_after>
                <observers><log><type>disabled</type></log></observers>
            </sales_quote_save_after>
            <checkout_quote_destroy>
                <observers><log><type>disabled</type></log></observers>
            </checkout_quote_destroy>
        </events>
    </frontend>
```

Or just download the module I've build for this.
https://github.com/sandermangel/sama_disablelog

Comment: Hi I have enabled my exception and set error notifying email. However I haven't received email notice or error log

Comment: There might be a fatal error. Di you check the apache errors logs?

Comment: IF so it should print via browser isn't?

Comment: Depends on your settings, on production I never output errors to screen. And a cronjob runs from the commandline

Comment: There is no fatal error Sander... I am sure about that but not about cron

Comment: I've updated my answer with another suggestion that might help you get more info. With the current information its hard to pin down the issue

Comment: Let me check with the Aoe and let you know, Because I don't want to entirely disable log...

Comment: No heartbeat task found. Check if cron is configured correctly. This was the error from AOE

Comment: Sounds like the cron.php is not being called properly by the cronjob